# Доступ к private членам шаблонного класса

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

```
template<size_t n> 
class A
{
    int x;

public:
    void foo() {
        A<1> a;
        //a.x; // Как получить прямой доступ к x для инстанциаций A<i>, i != 1?
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так сойдет?

```
template<size_t n> 
class A
{
    int x;

    template<size_t u>
        friend class A;

public:
    void foo() {
        A<5> a5;
        cout << a5.x;
        A<2> a2;
        cout << a2.x;
    }
};



int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    A<8> x;
    x.foo();
}
```

Comment: а проще нельзя?

Comment: @vlad, странная конструкция. Какую цель вы преследуете таким дизайном класса?

Comment: @Majestio что именно странного? для выполнения функции нужен объект с другим параметром, все параметры вычисляются в compile time, что предотвращает ошибки, например

Comment: Имхо, несколько нарушается принцип инкапсуляции. Локальный объект класса А по отношению с самому объекту класса А является сторонним. А странное то, что метод foo - работает не со "своими полями". Переменную "х" вы спрятали в приватную секцию. Поэтому выхода два: первый указали - объявить дружбу, второй - для переменной создать публичный метод-геттер, возможно с constexpr.

Comment: @Majestio вам нужно сделать с классом какие-то операции и вернуть результат, не изменяя его; каким образом вы это сделаете без создания локальной копии? для этого сделано так, что в классе есть доступ к приватным полям любой локальной переменной того же типа; в моем примере тип получается другой, поэтому приходится извращаться

Comment: "сделать с классом какие-то операции и вернуть результат" в compile-time?